# Take a reference if lvalue and make a copy if rvalue i.e. make rvalue persistent

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, rvalue, template-argument-deduction

I'm pretty new in move and lvalue semantics. And I have the impression I'm doing it wrong. Here 
the code I want to be able to write once `FunctContainer` is implemented:

```
std::function<double(double)> f = [](double x){return (x * x - 1); };

FunctContainer fc1 = FunctContainer(f);

FunctContainer fc2 = FunctContainer([](double x){return (x * x - 1); });
```

I want to write `FunctContainer`'s ctors so that the lifetime of the function stored in `fc1` is the one of `f` and the lifetime in `fc2` of the contained function is the lifetime of `fc2` itself.

I have written something (see below) but I'm not really satisfied (I got it wrong).

This is correct c++ but wrong behavior: `f_` expires after the call to the constructor when `f_` is an rvalue.

```
class FunctContainerWRONG{
public:
  IntegrandNotProjecting(const std::function<double(double)>& function)
    : f_(function){}
  IntegrandNotProjecting(const std::function<double(double)>&& function)
    : f_(std::move(function)){}
  const std::function<double(double)>& f_;
private:
};
```

This looks awful at me and probably is not correct c++ but is intended to explain in pseudocode what the desired behavior looks like. If possible I want to avoid to constuct a brand new object and I just want to let my object "persist":

```
class FunctContainer{
public:
  FunctContainer(const std::function<double(double)>& function)
    : f_p(nullptr), 
      f_(function){}
  FunctContainer(const std::function<double(double)>&& function)
    : f_p()std::make_shared<std::function<double(double)>>(function)), 
      f_(*f_p){}
private:
    std::shared_ptr<std::function<double(double)>> f_p;
    const std::function<double(double)>& f_;
};
```

Comment: So what is actually wrong with a last example (besides inconsistent ownership and lifetime management)? It can use `unique_ptr` though because ownership is not shared anyway.

Comment: @VTT what I really don't like in the last example is the fact that if function is an rvalue I say I want to make a copy, but I'd rather prefer to tell explicitely to the compiler to optimize it out. Moreover, as you point out the pointer should be unique if I have an rvalue and shared in the other case. This means that I need one more pointer and manage these pointers.

Answer (score 4):

*Forwarding references* and *reference collapsing* rules can help you achieve this easily.

```
template <typename T>
struct FunctContainer 
{
    T _f;

    template <typename TFwd>
    FunctContainer(TFwd&& f) : _f{std::forward<TFwd>(f)} { }
};

template <typename T>
auto makeFunctContainer(T&& f) -> FunctContainer<T>
{
    return {std::forward<T>(f)};
}
```

- When you invoke `makeFunctContainer` with an **lvalue**, `T` will be an *lvalue reference*. This means that you'll store an *lvalue reference* inside `FucntContainer`.
- When you invoke `makeFunctContainer` with an **rvalue**, `T` will be a *value*. This means that you'll store a *value* inside `FucntContainer`.

---

Example usage:

```
auto fc0 = makeFunctContainer(std::move(f0)); // `fc0` owns `f0`
auto fc1 = makeFunctContainer(f1); // `fc1` stores a reference to `f1`
```

Answer (score 2):

Since C++17 there is class template argument deduction with user-defined deduction guides ([Class Template Argument Deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)). With that you can solve your problem as follows:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename FnT>
struct FunctContainer {
    constexpr FunctContainer(FnT f) : f_ { std::forward<FnT>(f) } {}

    FnT f_;
};

template<typename FnT>
FunctContainer(const FnT& f) -> FunctContainer<const FnT&>;

template<typename FnT>
FunctContainer(FnT&& f) -> FunctContainer<FnT>;

int
main(
) {
    auto f { [] { std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl; } };

    FunctContainer f1 { f }; // stores reference to f in f1
    FunctContainer f2 { [] { std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl; } }; // moves f into f2

    f1.f_();
    f2.f_();

    return 0;
}
```