# Make rvalues persist as pointers in a recursive class

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, temporary, object-lifetime

I have a simple linked list node class which I can use to create a list `1->2->3` like so:

```
struct ListNode {
    int data_;
    ListNode *child_;
    ListNode(int data, ListNode *child) : data_{data}, child_{child} {}
};

ListNode node3(3, &node4);
ListNode node2(2, &node3);
ListNode head(1, &node2);
```

I want to make this construction less verbose by adding a new constructor, allowing something to the effect of:

```
ListNode head(1, (2, (3, nullptr)));
```

Essentially, I'd like the temporary objects created in the constructor to persist so I can point to them. How can I achieve this?

I've found an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591455/take-a-reference-if-lvalue-and-make-a-copy-if-rvalue-i-e-make-rvalue-persistent) but I this doesn't handle the recursive structure in my class definition. I've been looking at move semantics but can't understand how to make it work with `child` being a pointer type.

Comment: You can't move `child_`, you can only move `data_` but moving an `int` is pointless. You have to copy the list if you want to do this recursively. A better way might be to support initializer lists so you can do `ListNode head{1,2,3};` You still have to allocate `ListNode`s for `2` and `3` but you skip having the temporary nodes.

Comment: You should have a `class List` that has a `ListNode *head = nullptr;` and a constructor for `List{1,2,3}`. Would be cleaner that way. You can also improve a lot of functions if `List` has a `ListNode **tail = &head;`.

Comment: This cannot be done, as described. C++ does not work this way.

Comment: Unlike L value references, R value references cannot be be used to initialize via constructor arguments. Only via aggregate initialization.

Comment: Why not use `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers, and create new nodes in the constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably like to have the concept of a List to supplement your Node.
In combination with an `initializer_list` this can get quite neat.

Something like

```
#include <iostream>

struct ListNode {
    int data_;
    ListNode *child_;
    ListNode(int data, ListNode *child) : data_{data}, child_{child} {}
};

struct List{
    ListNode* head = nullptr;
    List(std::initializer_list<int> list){
        for(auto val:list){
            insert(val);
        }
    }
    void insert(int value){
        head = new ListNode(value, head);
    }
};
```

now you can create it with something like

```
int main() {
    List list = {3, 2, 1};
}
```

See https://godbolt.org/z/sn6orf5h9

Now, there are plenty of improvements to be made here of course, some mentioned in the comments. But that was not what you were asking for.